# Book where girl saves Hippogriffs feathers taken with wax

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book in 5th grade, around 2006-2007. I remember strong details of the book, but unfortunately can’t seem to remember details that would help me find it.

The book starts out on the beach for a ceremony of sorts with their children who all live in a monastery of sorts. The main character hears a high pitched sound in her head and passes out. She is then recognized as the person from a prophecy.

There is a boy, who is also her counterpart. Everyone always thinks he is the one with the powers. At one point they are in a cave and people are trying to find them and the girl has to wear a hood to hide something physical on her that shows she has the powers. It’s blue, whatever it is - it might be blue hair?

Past this point the big thing I remember is that she wants to save a flying fantasy animal with feathers. They might be hippogriffs. They are having all their feathers plucked from them using wax.

I know there are lots of sword fights and meeting royalty. They travel far.

Does anyone know the name of this book?